# VBA Number formatting currency 2dp

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I need to show a range of numbers as currency to 2dp and am using this:

`Sheets("Home").Range("Table2[Profit P/H]").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"`

but where it should show £1.46 it rounds to 1,  (zero decimal places & no currency symbols)

Please help

Comment: Can't repro this, it works as intended for me.

Comment: are you sure that the values in `Table2[Profit P/H]` are not text?

Comment: No I don't think they are text, after I have run VBA if I right click to check the format cells/number  it has "number" & "0dp". In my original file it is formatted as I want but when I run VBA to make some updates (move values to another sheet...) excel has seemingly changed the appearance of the cell value even though The VBA includes no instruction to change the format, I really don't get it :(

Comment: Try using the LCID:  `[$-en-UK]£#,##0.00`  If that doesn't work, check your windows regional setting for the decimal and number grouping symbols.

Comment: thanks for your help. after much messing around with copying formats from other columns which still didn't work - I tried using the macro recorder (for about the 50th time) and it finally worked - absolutely no clue what I was doing wrong but at least it is working now, time will tell how long for. Is it just me or is VBA really temperamental?